# How can I run a ColdFusion 9 application in Apache?

Tags: apache, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, ear, application.cfm

I received the artifacts of a legacy application (probably 2000-2005) written in Adobe ColdFusion 9, together with a SQL data export file.
If I want to migrate the data to a newer application, I need to be able to run this thing.
I've been trying all day to get it running.
I've installed Adobe ColdFusion 9, added the datasource, added a context binding, etc. but I can't find out how I can run this.
Is there a way to package this to an .ear or .war file, or just run the .cfm files by themselves (like .HTML or .PHP)?

Comment: If your installation was successful, then you just run the cfm files.  ColdFusion is interpreted so there's nothing to compile.

Comment: Do you need to migrate only the data? Or do you need to replicate the functionality of the application in a new system? Have you restored the SQL data export to a new database? Have you opened any `cfm` pages yet? You don't say how you added the Apache binding, but it sounds like you probably still need to run the `wsconfig` tool to get the `LoadModule` and `AddHandler` directives added to your Apache conf. 
https://www.3gpp2.org/cfdocs/htmldocs/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fd7.html 
https://www.3gpp2.org/cfdocs/htmldocs/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fd9.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Coldfusion 9 isn't supported anymore and has plenty of vulnerabilities exposed, I wouldn't take the path to install it. If you want to reactivate that app I'd run it with updated and supported software. As a quick solution I'd just download and install CommandBox from Ortus Solutions, open a command line terminal in the applications webroot folder and run 'box server start'. That will run a Lucee server instance and open your application in the browser. Lucee can do pretty good with old legacy cfml. Of course, it will depend on your base code and the use of specific ACF features your application may need.You can also choose and run an  ACF engine with CommandBox. From there you'll probably see your application generating errors and you'll need to identify those and correct them. Second step would be to import your SQL data to a running database. That step depend on the data and DBMS you want to run.